# Problem with detecting user who moved member from other channel (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_voice_state_update(self, member, before, after):  # Gold Standard
        print(f"on_voice_state_update triggered for user: {member.id}")
        guild = member.guild
        if before.channel and after.channel and before.channel != after.channel:
            if guild.me.guild_permissions.view_audit_log:
                await asyncio.sleep(1)  
                async for entry in guild.audit_logs(limit=5, action=discord.AuditLogAction.member_move):                    
                    if entry.target == member and (entry.channel.id == before.channel.id or entry.channel.id == after.channel.id):
                        mover = entry.user
                        break
                else:
                    mover = None  
                if mover:
                    await self.on_voice_state_switched_by_other(member, before, after, mover)
                else:
                    await self.on_voice_state_switched(member, before, after)  
            else:
                await self.on_voice_state_switched(member, before, after)  
        elif before.channel and not after.channel:
            await self.on_voice_state_left(member, before, after)
        elif not before.channel and after.channel:
            await self.on_voice_state_joined(member, before, after)
```

I have this code that fetches audit logs to determine whether a user moved by themselves or if another user with the appropriate permissions moved a user. Then, this method calls another method to send an embed in the logs. However, the bot seems to think that the user moved channels by themselves all the time, regardless of whether another user moved them.